# Display part of Webpage in c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am developing a C# windows application in which I use a WebBrowser control to display a webpage. I would like to display only a particular region of that web page.

The webpage is : http://vhg.cmp.uea.ac.uk/tech/jas/vhg2018/WebGLAv.html

... and I'd like to display just the textbox of "SiGML Text", the "Play SiGML Text" button and the animation in my application.

I use this code in my program:
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://vhg.cmp.uea.ac.uk/tech/jas/vhg2018/WebGLAv.html");

but I just see this image in my program:
[webbrowser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtNSL.jpg)

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors do you get?

Comment: I tried alot but I don't know why webbrowser doesn't show this animation and the text box.

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong? Since you never showed us any of your code there is no way we can know.

Comment: "I tried alot" doesn't quite tell us **what** you've tried :) I would recommend that you edit the post with the code that you tried to use and tell us **where** you're getting the error, if you are getting one. That way we can see what you may be doing wrong/incorrectly :)

Comment: I edit the post. Can you help me? I really need your help.